# How to make the sound of Light Bike Tron Legacy

Tags: sound-design, sound, film, scifi

After watching "Tron Legacy" I've thought that the sound was really good, and particularly the sound of the Light Bike.

So I've started wondering, how did they make these sounds?

Of course there are some real motorbike sounds but how did they make the other sounds.

I've searched on the internet for clues, and I didn't find anything convincing. So here's my question How did they make the Light Bike ?

If anybody has clues, or ideas I'll appreciate :)

Thank you.

Here's a link for the scene :

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about the ones from Tron Legacy, but for the original Tron, the light cycles are made using an Atari electronic tones, synths, and a buzz saw. Of course, these layers are double with a motorcycles.